# Programatically toggle Basemap labels

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online-basemaps

I can toggle the active basemap programmatically using the code below, but how can I also include a widget to show or hide the **basemap labels** programmatically?

```
myApp.widgets.basemapManager.basemapGallery.activeBasemap = {
  portalItem: {
      id: baseMapId
    }
```

I see no labels object or properties in the dev console for `activeBasemap`, how can I do this?

*I am using ArcGIS JS API 4*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can actually request the service with or without labels in a basemap. Generally the basemap will have or not, and only on selected features, depending the type of basemap that it is. If it is a political map, you may have the names of the continents, countries, states, counties, cities, towns. In the `streets` basemap the street names is a must. In the imagery for example you don't have labels, because you are showing satellite images. Of course there are mixed maps.

So, what I suggest you as a possibility is just the last thing I mention, mix maps. You can have two basemaps, one with labels and another without labels and switch them (*). Or you can have the basemap and then have a map service with the labels, that you can turn on/off. Witch approach you take will depend on the type of map you are building, the extent, the levels, etc. Making a good map is an art.

(*) Although this option will have the best time perform, it could be too expensive in disk, maintenance, and building time.